# Getting columns from dataframe when using groupby pandas python.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Age   Sex
10     M
20     M
30     F
15     F
```

and I want a dataframe that includes the average age per sex. That is:

```
Age   Sex  Average
10     M     15
20     M     15
30     F     22.5
15     F     22.5
```

However what I did was:

```
average = dataframe.groupby('Sex').mean()
```

And with that I would just use the join function. Nevertheless, the dataframe 
doesnt include sex as a column so I can't merge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use :

```
average = dataframe.groupby('Sex', as_index=False).mean()
```

set `as_index=False` will include `Sex` as a column in the result dataframe.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

No need to perform a merge, use `transform`:

```
dataframe['Average'] = dataframe.groupby('Sex').transform('mean')
```

In general, use `transform` when you want group level aggregates in the same shape as your original DataFrame.

The resulting output:

```
   Age Sex  Average
0   10   M     15.0
1   20   M     15.0
2   30   F     22.5
3   15   F     22.5
```